# Raytracer in odd or high level language

Tags: code-golf, code-challenge

Ray tracers are easy to write.  At each pixel on the screen, you shoot a ray into the scene and see what it hits.  For the most basic ray tracer, the ray acquires the color of the object it hit.

If you're doing shading, then you don't color the pixel immediately, instead you try to trace a ray back to the *light source*.  The shaded color is then the (color of the surface)*(cosine of the angle (dot product) of ray-to-the-lightsource has with the surface normal).  If the light source cannot be reached, then the object is in shadow.

This challenge is to write the raytracer in any language you can.  The winner is the most **succinct** code, while still remaining readable (see here for more [elegant definitions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/97914/13572)).

**Requirements**:

- Ray trace spheres
- Shading
- Shadows
- At least 1 bounce interreflection.
- You must display your result using pixels *or* write an image file.  Don't draw into the console.

**Bonus**:

- Include ability to ray trace general polygons
- Translucency

**Superbonus**:

- General BRDFs
- Subsurface scattering (BSSRDF)

**Bad examples**:

- **Don't do this:** http://www.teamten.com/lawrence/projects/shortest_ray_tracer/
- **And don't do this:** http://www.kevinbeason.com/smallpt/

The first is not readable.  The 2nd is just a really *compact* C++ program.

*This is a hard project*, so you might want to bookmark it and come back later.  I'll leave this open for about a month before awarding the checkmark.

## Resources:

- [http://www.cs.utah.edu/~shirley/irt/](http://www.cs.utah.edu/%7Eshirley/irt/)

(more will be added later)

Comment: Please read the site FAQ for what constitutes a good, well-specified question.

Comment: Ok, ok.  I'll flesh it out.

Comment: "the shortest _x_ you can" (code-golf) and "while still remaining intelligible to read" are incompatible. If it is code-golf, then the objective measure is character count. "intelligible" is subjective, and prone to taste. In which case this should be code-challenge. Please pick one.

Comment: "The 2nd is just a really _compact_ C program". Nope, this is C++ program, and C++ is not C.

Comment: Instead of writing "bonus" and "superbonus", please make an objective winning criteria. For example: `code size - 20 * (number of bonuses met) - 50 * (number of super-bonuses met)` (I am not claiming that is a good criteria). You have this tagged as [tag:code-challenge], so that sort of criteria is expected.

Comment: Goraud shading in ray tracer? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @shiona Well it does, but it's incorrect.  I mean to say Phong.

Comment: "Ray tracers are easy to write" - I disagree. "The 2nd is just a really compact C++ program" - so what is wrong with it?

Comment: What is this I don't even... what does Rubik's cube have to do with raytracing?

Comment: It was just a joke.  1. You're free to disagree. 2. Ray tracers are _always_ written in C++.. how about something different?

Answer (score 7):

This needs a little more work to fulfill the requirements (shading, interreflection), but mostly works. It generates the pixels line-by-line in the callback procedure to the `image` operator. The readability comes at the expense of being very wasteful with memory, creating and discarding temporary arrays with abandon.

## Postscript 90 lines

Uses an external [matrix library](http://web.archive.org/web/20160404161539/https://code.google.com/p/xpost/downloads/detail?name=mat.ps&can=2&q=).

```
(mat.ps) run  % load matrix library
/div { dup 0 eq { pop 10000 }{ div } ifelse } bind def  % make divide-by-zero safe
/tan { dup sin exch cos div } def 

%[vector] scalar {op}  .  [vector']
%create a new vector and fill with the scalar,
%call matrix library's vector-op
/sop {
    exch % [] {} s
    [ exch % [] {} [ s 
    3 index length 1 sub{dup}repeat % [] {} [ s*n-1
    ] exch % [] [] {}  
    vop 
} def 

/normalize { dup mag {div} sop } def 

<< % parameters
    /Cam    [ 0 0 0 ]   % camera location
    /Lookat [ 0 0 -1 ]  % camera lookat point
    /Up     [ 0 1 0 ]   % up vector
    /fovx   45          % horizontal field of view
    /W      320         % image width
    /H      200         % image height
    /Sc     [ 1 1 -5 ]  % sphere center
    /Sr     2           % sphere radius
>> begin

<< % dependent constants
    /Left Lookat Cam {sub} vop Up cross
    /buf W string
    /fovy H W div fovx mul 
    /ang 0
    /pos 3
>> {def} forall  % add these values to existing dictionary

% place the light in the scene according to the /ang parameter
/setLight { /Light [ ang cos pos mul 3 ang sin pos mul ] def } def 

0 10 360 { /ang exch def   % for-loop sets /ang, calls image and showpage
setLight                   % place the light
150 200 translate          % position lower left corner of image on page
/y 0 def                   % initial y-value
W H 8                      % put width height depth on stack  for `image` call
[ 1 0 0 1 0 0 ]            % 1-to-1 matrix, so width*height points is the image size
{                          % image procedure yields a string with one image row 
    0 1 W 1 sub { /x exch def                   % for-loop iterates over x-values
        Left   x 2 mul W sub W div fovx tan mul  {mul} sop  % construct vector from eye through center of pixel
        Up     y 2 mul H sub H div fovy tan mul  {mul} sop 
        Lookat {add} vop {add} vop 
        Cam {sub} vop 
        normalize /R exch def 

        Cam Sc {sub} vop   % use the quadratic formula to check for real intersection
        dup R dot 2 mul /B exch def 
        dup dot Sr dup mul sub /C exch def 

        B dup mul C 4 mul sub /disc exch def  % discriminant, the part under the radical-sign

        % ray hits sphere? no:0 yes:calculate
        disc 0 lt { 0 }{
            disc sqrt /sdisc exch def  % complete the quadratic formula to yield t value
            B neg sdisc sub .5 mul /t exch def
            t 0 le { B neg sdisc add .5 mul /t exch def } if
            R t {mul} sop
            Cam {add} vop /ri exch def  %intersection point
            ri Sc {sub} vop
            1 Sr div {mul} sop %normalize
            /rn exch def  %surface normal
            Light
            ri
            {sub} vop %normalize
            rn dot  % normal .dot. light-ray
            1 add .3 mul
            %.3 mul
            dup 0 lt {pop 0} if  % clip value into 8-bit range
            dup 1 gt {pop 1} if
            255 mul truncate cvi
        } ifelse   % pixel_color = 0..255

        buf x 3 2 roll put  % put pixel value in string
    } for
    /y y 1 add def  % increase y for next row
    buf  % yield string buffer to image
}
%exec  % image doesn't report internal errors, debug the procedure with `exec`
image
showpage

} bind for
```

Can generate a numbered series of images using ghostscript. And ImageMagick's `convert` can compile them into an animated gif.

[image]

Comment: You're pretty insane.  How did you get so good at PS anyway?

Comment: Obsession, and a really bad break-up :). ... More seriously, trying to implement the interpreter itself has greatly improved my ps coding skills.